# why does pygame.display.update stop working after being called a set number of times?

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-surface

When running I am blit'ing some text onto my surface (WIN) and I want this to be shown in the game so I call pygame.display.update to update the display, this works perfectly fine until the loop has iterated around 75 times and after this the display stops updating. Code below

```
def dialogue(x,y,text):
    global clock
    global run
    typing=True
    tempstring=""
    counter=0
    switcher=0
    for z in range(0,(len(text))):
        clock.tick(15)
        tempstring=text[0:z+1]
        counter+=1
        print(counter)
        print("temp is "+tempstring)
        writing=TITLE_FONT.render(tempstring, 1, (255,255,255),(0,0,0))
        if x==-1 and y>-1:
            pygame.display.update(WIN.blit(writing, (640-(writing.get_width()//2),y-(writing.get_height()//2))))
        elif x>-1 and y==-1:
            pygame.display.update(WIN.blit(writing, (x-(writing.get_width()//2),360-(writing.get_height()//2))))
        elif x==-1 and y==-1:
            pygame.display.update(WIN.blit(writing, (640-(writing.get_width()//2),360-(writing.get_height()//2))))
        else:
            pygame.display.update(WIN.blit(writing, (x-(writing.get_width()//2),y-(writing.get_height()//2))))
    
    print(typing)
    while True:
        event = pygame.event.wait()
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run=False
            pygame.quit()
            break
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            break
```

I have tried just using pygame.display.update() at the end of the line of if statements too but this also fails.

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
Your posted code merely defines a function and stops without calling it.

Comment: We expect you to perform basic diagnosis to include with your post.  At the very least, print the suspected values at the point of error and trace them back to their sources.  In many cases, doing this basic diagnosis will show you where the problem lies, and you won't need Stack Overflow at all.

Comment: I've already done basic diagnostic to see where the actual error lies and it's in the function, so I asked here, where there is a wealth of experience, if someone has had the same issue as me before. If I hadn't tasted and covered the basics, I wouldn't have needed to ask for a more complex solution, so I wouldn't have needed to ask.

Comment: on some systems it doesn't work correctly if you don't get `pygame.event` from system - system may think that program hangs and it may even close it. You may need to use `pygame.even.get()` inside your loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On some systems `PyGame` doesn't work correctly if you don't get `pygame.event` from system - system may think that program hangs and it may even close it.

You may need to use `pygame.even.get()` (or similar functions) inside your loop.

---

In doc [pygame.event](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html) you can find (but it is hidden in long description)

> To prevent lost events, especially input events which signal a quit command, your program must handle events every frame (with pygame.event.get(), pygame.event.pump(), pygame.event.wait(), pygame.event.peek() or pygame.event.clear()) and process them.

> Not handling events may cause your system to decide your program has locked up.

> To keep pygame in sync with the system, you will need to call pygame.event.pump() internally process pygame event handlers to keep everything current.